# How to style GWT's NotificationMole with CSS

Tags: css, gwt

Has anyone had any success applying your own CSS style to GWT's NotificationMole.

If I add my own stylename then that style only applies to the outer DIV which is NOT removed when the mole is hidden, and I can't fing a way to apply style to the inner divs...

Answer (score 1):

A dirty solution :

```
package com.google.gwt.user.client.ui; // important for package visibility access

import com.google.gwt.dom.client.DivElement;
import com.google.gwt.dom.client.SpanElement;

public class NotificationMoleHelper {

    protected NotificationMole notificationMole;

    public NotificationMoleHelper(NotificationMole notificationMole) {
        super();
        this.notificationMole = notificationMole;
    }

    public SpanElement getNotificationText() {
        return notificationMole.notificationText;
    }

    public DivElement getHeightMeasure() {
        return notificationMole.heightMeasure;
    }

public DivElement getBorderElement() {
    return notificationMole.borderElement;
}

    /**
     * Change heightMeasure's background color
     * 
     * @param backgroundColor
     */
    public void setBackgroundColor(String backgroundColor) {

        getBorderElement().getStyle().setBackgroundColor(backgroundColor);
    }
}
```

Example :

```
final NotificationMoleHelper notificationMoleHelper = new NotificationMoleHelper(notificationMole);
notificationMoleHelper.setBackgroundColor("#FF1111");
```

Answer (score 0):

Well your NotificationMole has an associated ui.xml file, so any custom styles you want to apply should be applied there.

Comment: I've looked at it, and it only declares "in-line" styles in the UiBinder file. I'm not great on CSS but I don't think I can set styles according to those names.   If you inspect a NM element there are styles defined for each of the "in-line" styles, with wierd names that look like they are generated by the GWT compiler. Using those I can style it, but I suspect that will break at next GWT release when the names change.

Answer (score 0):

This might be easy: define your own style first, after init of the NotificationMole, just replace its built-in class with your defined ones, that's what i did in my project. Using DOM to replace classes or using gwtquery, both are OK.

Answer (score 0):

A further alternative which might be more palatable for some people:

1. Set the id of the mole `mole.getElement().setId("mole");` or `mole.ensureDebugId("mole")`
2. Then in your ui binder file add style:

   ````
       width: 200px !important;
           height: 60px !important;
   }```
   ````

I tried without the !importants but gwt was including default widths and height so it wasn't listening to my styling. You won't need the !important if you add styles that gwt doesn't add by default.